# Can't set custom typeface inside ViewHolder

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-viewholder

I've tried everything that I could find on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work.

The problem is that I cant change the font of any TextView inside my CardViewLayout.

I've tried font family, text appearance in xml
I've changed it by doing this, but I'm getting the error **Cannot resolve symbol 'itemView'**

code:

```
public class cardAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<cardModel> {

public cardAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, 0);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View contentView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (contentView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(contentView);
        contentView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) contentView.getTag();
    }

    cardModel spot = getItem(position);

    holder.title.setText(spot.title);
    holder.description.setText(spot.description);
    Glide.with(getContext()).load(spot.url).into(holder.image);

    return contentView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {

    public TextView title;
    public TextView description;
    public ImageView image;

    Typeface customTypeOne = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/typefaceone.ttf");

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        this.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setTypeface(customTypeOne);
        this.description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        this.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And where is `itemView` declared?

Comment: I tried to declare it in public ViewHolder, I got freed of errors but when I launch the app it crashes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your attempt and the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I'm getting the error Cannot resolve symbol 'itemView'

That is because you do not have anything named `itemView`.

First, replace:

```
Typeface customTypeOne = Typeface.createFromAsset(itemView.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/typefaceone.ttf");
```

with:

```
Typeface customTypeOne;
```

Then, in your `ViewHolder` constructor, at the bottom, add:

```
customTypeOne = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.title.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/typefaceone.ttf");
```

Now you are calling `getContext()` on something that exists.

Comment: I was just about to edit the code in the question, I've done that already, however when I launch the activity, it crashes

Comment: @newbieCoder.pkg: Then use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Hmm guess the error is that the font asset is not found. That makes it easy then :). Thanks a lot man.